# Ruby Win32Api get single character non-blocking

Tags: ruby, winapi, input, nonblocking

I'm trying to write a simple game working with two threads, one thread to get input from the user, and another thread to animate some scenes.  I'm able to get characters without pressing ENTER just fine, but it blocks in the animating thread until the user presses a key.  Does anyone know of a way to get a character from the keyboard non-blocking?

Comment: so what you're saying is with ruby 1.8, in windows, if one thread does a "getc" then the other thread is also blocked, and you want a fix for that? Or do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to checkup on a handful of specific keys, `GetAsyncKeyState()` can be used to poll for state. Otherwise, you should implement a message loop and handle `WM_CHAR` messages in your application.

You can access raw win32 functions with a library similar to the following if your environment doesn't already support the win32 functions you need.

[RAA - win32-api @ raa.ruby-lang.org](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/win32-api/)

Here are relevant links for `GetAsyncKeyState()`.

[GetAsyncKeyState() @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28VS.85%29.aspx)
[Virtual-Key Codes @ MSDN (used as values for GetAsyncKeyState and other functions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

If you decide to go with a message loop, you'll need to implement it on the same thread that hosts the window for your application. A short explanation is available here:

[Message Loop in Microsoft Windows @ Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows)

As shown at that link, there isn't a whole lot to a message loop. Your framework may already have one running behind the scenes to host the window containing your graphics. If this is the case, you don't need a 2nd thread for input; but you will need to intercept and handle windows messages for that host window.

If you have to implement a message loop on your own, you can use the skeleton at the wikipedia link. The `DispatchMessage` call will direct a windows message to the appropriate window handler. You will need to look for a matching stub or handler for windows messages in your ruby framework, and handle `WM_CHAR` from there.

[DispatchMessage @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644934%28VS.85%29.aspx)
[WM_CHAR @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646276%28VS.85%29.aspx)

If you wish to know when keys are pressed/depressed, then you will want to handle WM_KEYUP and WM_KEYDOWN messages.

[WM_KEYUP @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646281%28VS.85%29.aspx)
[WM_KEYDOWN @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Also note, `GetAsyncKeyState()` can be called and returns key state even while another application is in the foreground. Handle `WM_ACTIVATE` and `WM_SETFOCUS`/`WM_KILLFOCUS` messages so that your application ignores or defers checks while a different window is active if you only care about key state while your window is the primary foreground window.

[WM_ACTIVATE @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646274%28VS.85%29.aspx)
[WM_SETFOCUS @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646283%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
[WM_KILLFOCUS @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646282%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [rubygame](http://rubygame.org/) for this. It gives you the ability to attach functions to keyboard events with minimal code.  [RubySDL](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubysdl/) and [GoSu](http://code.google.com/p/gosu/) will give you similar functionality.

If you don't want to go that route with game related gems take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779347/using-rubys-ready-io-method-with-gets-puts-etc) on how to check if data is available in IO object. This could be use to poll the keyboard.